# Remove PHP extension from page naming function

Tags: php, html

How can I remove the script extension from this function?

```
<?php
function curPageName() {
 return substr($_SERVER["SCRIPT_NAME"],strrpos($_SERVER["SCRIPT_NAME"],"/")+1);
}

echo "The current page name is ".curPageName();
?>
```

For instance, it will echo The current page name is `index.php`. How can I remove the `.php` ?

Comment: Add `,-4` right after the `+1`?

Comment: @NiettheDarkAbsol This was a script I found on google, I didn't write it.

Comment: try this simple option `rtrim($_SERVER["SCRIPT_NAME"], ".php")`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

try `substr()`

```
echo "The current page name is ".substr(curPageName(),0,-4);
```

will cut last four char from string and return remain string like:-

```
echo substr('sdgfjsgdfj.php',0,-4); //returns sdgfjsgdfj 

0 = start of string, -4 = remove string from back limit
substr ( string $string , int $start [, int $length ] )
```

so if you want remove `.php` then char length is 4 so need to pass `-4` and need result from start so starting from `0` to last strip `-4` staring

For more follow manual :- http://php.net/manual/en/function.substr.php

Comment: in case filname have `abcd.phpd.php`??

Comment: All answers to this question will come with assumptions. In your case, this assumes that `/path/to/something.phpfunctions.php` isn't a thing.

Comment: @NiettheDarkAbsol added also substr()

Comment: @RakeshSharma Which is basically my answer, and you have failed to explain any of the shortcomings of either solution.

Comment: @NiettheDarkAbsol please echo your result and see what you get

Comment: Still doesn't explain the reason for using these codes, or the risks involved (edge cases etc.)

Comment: @NiettheDarkAbsol so what you don't get? try it let me know if you don't get expected

Comment: I fully understand your answer. However, considering the question is so simple it's fairly safe to assume that you should *explain your answer* rather than just throwing code around.

Comment: @NiettheDarkAbsol check now if you still didn't get i can't describe more

Comment: As I keep on saying, *I* understand your answer perfectly fine. However, *someone else* might not understand that `str_replace` may replace more than just what was intended.

Answer (score 0):

Strip everything behind the last dot, regardless of file ending (and because I like regular expressions):

```
  <?php
    function curPageName() {
      return preg_replace('#\..+?$#','',$_SERVER['SCRIPT_NAME']);
    }
  ?>
```

If you want to remove the path in front as well:

```
  <?php
    function curPageName() {
      return preg_replace('#\..+?$#','',basename($_SERVER['SCRIPT_NAME']));
    }
  ?>
```

Comment: `?` is hindering here because of the `$` - you *want* to match as much as possible. `i` is useless because there are no letters in the regex itself. `s` is probably a bad idea just on account of there being no newlines in a script name...

Comment: Actually the ? is a very good idea, because you will only remove the last part after ".". If there are multiple occurences of ".", e.g. "index.en.php", it will return "index.en". But for "i" & "s" you are perfectly right :)

Comment: Hmm... actually, you'd be better off with `\.[^.]+`, as this will avoid any complications from there being multiple `.`s.

Comment: Don't need it - `.` has no meaning inside `[]`.

Answer (score -1):

If it can be safely assumed that all of your PHP scripts have `.php` as a file extension (and not, for instance, `.php5` or whatever), then you can do:

```
substr($_SERVER['SCRIPT_NAME'],strrpos($_SERVER['SCRIPT_NAME'],"/")+1,-4);
```

The `-4` will cut off the `.php` from the end.

Comment: echo substr('fsgdjh.php',-4);?

Comment: @RakeshSharma Does exactly what I say it should: `fsgdjh`.

Comment: @RakeshSharma You mean your answer which ripped off my code in your edit, but without explaining the shortcomings?